# Which graphic style is that?

Tags: style-identification, graphic-styles

does anybody know how this graphic style is called ?[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  There are several graphical elements in the image. Which style do you mean?  The cartoon illustration, the flower, the fonts, the backgrounds, the rectangles, the page layout, etc?  Can you please read the [Style Identification Requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/what-are-the-requirements-for-style-identification-questions) page, and [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/122266/edit) to add the missing information. Thanks.

Comment: Just a cartoon?

Answer (score 2):

White Beard numb leg lotus. There are several graphic elements there. You have a simple high contrast background with a cartoon vector over a geometric mandala type lotus..?

Comment: Thanks for contributing! But if a question is unclear as to what it's asking, please flag it as unclear and don't answer it.

Comment: I believe that my answer was helpful. Sometimes people do not know the right questions to ask right off and need direction or additional information themselves before they can narrow it down.

Comment: Your answer is just describing what we can see in the image, check [answer] to learn more.